# Not able to check vault status, getting error checking seal status

Tags: command-line-interface, hashicorp-vault

I have enabled TLS, using the environment variable `VAULT_ADDR=https://127.0.0.1:8200`, but it shows some error while unsealing or even checking the vault status.

I tried changing the environment variable to `VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200`, that time it works, but i have enabled tls in my hcl file

My hcl file

```
backend "file" {
path = "/home/***/vault/"
}
listener "tcp" {
address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
tls_disable = 0
tls_cert_file = "/home/***/vault/vault.crt"
tls_key_file = "/home/***/vault/vault.key"
}
```

```
Error checking seal status: Get https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/seal-status: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Yes, i am, but the TLS is not being enabled only

Comment: now it's working fine after restarting the remote system. Maybe the old commands were cached